# iptables: No chain/target/match by that name - adding SSH ATTACK rule

Tags: ssh, iptables, ip, internet

I have a problem with adding rule against brute-force SSH attacks. I try to do it in the following way:

```
iptables -F
iptables -L
iptables -N SSHATTACK
iptables -A SSHATTACK -j LOG --log-prefix "Possible SSH attack! " --log-level 7
iptables -A SSHATTACK -j DROP
#Block each IP address for 120 seconds which establishe more than three connections within 120 seconds. In case of the forth connection attempt, the request gets delegated to the SSHATTACK chain, which is responsible for logging the possible ssh attack and finally drops the request.
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp -m state --dport 22 --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp -m state --dport 22 --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 120 --hitcount 4 -j SSHATTACK
```

But I have a problem with these two lines:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp -m state --dport 22 --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp -m state --dport 22 --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 120 --hitcount 4 -j SSHATTACK
```

Output after this command is

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

`iptables -L` gives the following output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain SSHATTACK (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level debug prefix `Possible SSH attack! '
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

and `iptables -S` gives:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N SSHATTACK
-A SSHATTACK -j LOG --log-prefix "Possible SSH attack! " --log-level 7
-A SSHATTACK -j DROP
```

`ip add` gives (I've hiden IP adress with '?'):

```
1 lo LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    linkloopback 000000000000 brd 000000000000
    inet 127.0.0.18 scope host lo
    inet6 1128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2 venet0 BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    linkvoid
    inet 127.0.0.132 scope host venet0
    inet ?.?.?.24820 brd ?.?.?.255 scope global venet00
```

What can I do to add this rule? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but if anyone gets here this might help (solved for me).

The issue is a missing kernel driver. After adding

> CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RECENT=y

to the kernel config and recompiling it, the problem was solved.
You can also add it as a module (=m) and insmod it at runtime

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The `--dport` parameter doesn't belong inside the `state` match. Try:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. I got the same error.

Comment: Works for me. Can you add any entries to the INPUT table for that interface? Post interface info (ip add).

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
I don't know how to check other entries, do you have any sample input? This is production server, so I don't want to brake anything :)


My question is edited (I've add ip add output).

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

You could reduce your own ruleset's complexity and allow something like `fail2ban` to manage it for you. Available in a CentOS 7 package repository near you, or downloadable via EPEL on CentOS 6.

Fail2ban has rules ready made for blocking `ssh` attacks, and there are a couple of tutorials [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-6) or [here](http://felipeferreira.net/index.php/2008/10/securing-your-ssh-with-fail2ban/).

Comment: I've just tried it but it doesn't seem to work. There is a new entry in iptables -L, but when I keep trying to log in with wrong passwords I don't get banned

Comment: @michalsol you enabled the `ssh` rule in `fail2ban`'s configuration as per the instructions, and restarted the daemon? You should see information in `/var/log/fail2ban.log`

Comment: Yes, I've done everything according to tutorial. In log file I just see that it has started but no info about blocking

Comment: @michalsol you have the `fail2ban` daemon running, and in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` you have a section for `ssh` that includes `enabled = true`?

Comment: Yes, enabled=true is set, and I've started fail2ban using 'sudo service fail2ban restart'

Comment: When you log in (with a bad password) does it trigger a corresponding message in `/var/log/auth.log`? This is what `fail2ban` matches against, per its `logpath = /var/log/auth.log` entry for `ssh`.

Comment: In [ssh-iptables] section it is set: logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log, but this file is not even created, even after login with bad passowrd

Comment: @michalsol you need to find where your ssh authentication failure messages are logged, and update the `logpath` entry appropriately. On my Debian system it's `/var/log/auth.log`. On other systems it may be elsewhere in `/var/log`.

Comment: Thank you! I've completely misunderstood meanning of logpath, I thought it was just a place where fail2ban logs information. Now I'm getting banned properly after typing bad password :)
But I have some issue - I get banned after some time, it is not immediate. How can I fix it?

Comment: @michalsol you're not generally expected to get banned immediately. There are parameters that control the number of wrong events and the time period in which they must happen. You could reduce it to one wrong attempt but you'd be better off setting it at, say, two attempts in one minute. If this answer helped you please use the tick mark to accept it.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I've set it to 3 faulty login attempts made in 600 seconds, but after trying to log in third time I get banned after ~30 seconds more, not immtediate.